# How can I install Ubuntu 18.04 on a different Mirrored HDD from my Windows OS?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid

So a little bit of context first. I use a Desktop PC that has a 120GB SSD with Windows 10 installed on it and two 1TB HDDs that are on RAID 1 so the OS only sees an 1TB HDD (I have files equal of 400GB in it). What I want to do is, keeping the RAID 1 on my HDDs, install Ubuntu 18.04 on a new partition created from the RAID 1. So what I tried doing was to use the Shrink Volume option from Windows' Disk Management so I can shrink my current RAID 1 and free 300GB for the Ubuntu.

This is what my Devices and Drivers looks like on Windows' File Explorer:
[Devices and drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix9if.png)

So after making a USB bootable with Ubuntu 18.04 using Rufus, I booted from it and went for the installation process. After clicking the "Something else" option this is what appeared: [Installation Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l42Lu.jpg)
There is a last option bellow `/dev/sda1` that can be seen in that image: [Scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymCRD.jpg)

With the Device for boot loader installation menu open: [Devices for boot loader installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgWIk.jpg)

(I am sorry for the bad quality of the images, I really didn't know how to screen capture at that point)

I have tried to install on Mirror2 using several combinations with the help of some tutorials I found here but all of them failed in the end. Fortunately I did not lose any data on my HDD or SSD. So my question is what should I select there or what else could I do to achieve what I want? Is it normal that there are so many "devices" appearing on the menu? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu to a RAID array seems unwise - it adds unnecessary boot-time complexity and will be hard to maintain. Example: The entire RAID must spin up in order to access the bootloader. Have you considered partitioning your SSD, or simply using a VM Guest on the Windows Host?

Comment: Partitioning my SSD is a bad option for me because 120GB for two Operating Systems will not be enough I think. About the VM on Windows that's what I am using right now but I will need something more efficient for the future, that's why I want to go for a dual boot solution. I see your point about installing Ubuntu to a RAID, so I think I will just remove the RAID and install it on the second HDD. Thank you for answering!

Comment: 60GB per OS is a huge amount...if you're not storing big media files on the SSD (which is unwise anyway). Ubuntu, like Windows, boots much faster and is much more responsive operating from an SSD. Otherwise, months from now, you will complain about how Windows is so much faster than Ubuntu...you set it up that way.